# Development using typescript and production debugging with Component-preload.js

Tags: sapui5

I am working on the SAPUI5 application with normal ES5 code and using `grunt-openui5` to create the `Component-preload.js` file to deploy to CRM system. Now I am planning to use ES6 style coding but we need to support an old browser. Therefore, I need to transpile it down to ES5 and then create the `Component-preload.js` file. Now my concern with this approach is when I debug the production issue, everyone gets it right, I want to debug my ES6 file, not ES5 file.

Any help or guidance is very appreciated.

Comment: As someone who might need to upgrade or maintain your app, don't use community efforts like typescript libraries for your production apps. There are no official typescript bindings at this point. I could live with Babel I think...

Comment: I understand what you saying and agree with you but I want to use ES6 now not Typescript. Using the latest Javascript coding style is the reason why I want to use ES6 but want to transpile it down to ES5 for production as we need to support the older browser but if I do that then I won't be able to debug my latest ES6 code due to component-preload.js file content

Comment: Yes you do, because the code that breaks things in production is the code that is transpiled. If you're determined, you can copy the original ES6 files as `_dbg.js` files and use `sap-ui-debug=true` url parameters to load them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to have a transpiled, debuggable preload file and separate ES6 based source files is probably to use the `sap-ui-debug=true` URL parameter option. Instead of the normal files, it will try to load `-dbg.js` versions of everything. This for instance is what the SAP WebIDE generates:

[image]

If you can set up your build set so that the original, untranspiled files are copied as `-dbg` versions, and your preload picks up the transpiled ones you might be able to make it work.

Here's the section of the SDK documentation that'll give you some more background information: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/c9b0f8cca852443f9b8d3bf8ba5626ab

Comment: I figured it out already and thanks for confirming it. Is there any other option though? Just curious

Comment: I believe this is the only way run a transpiled preload and have untranspiled debug files, but I wasn't 100% sure :)